# Issue after Spark Installation on Windows 10

Tags: scala, hadoop, apache-spark

This is a cmd log that I see after running spark-shell command (C:\Spark>spark-shell). As I understand, it's mainly an issue with Hadoop. I use Windows 10. Can somehow please with the below issue?

```
C:\Users\mac>cd c:\
c:\>winutils\bin\winutils.exe chmod 777 \tmp\hive
c:\>cd c:\spark
c:\Spark>spark-shell


Using Spark's default log4j profile: org/apache/spark/log4j-defaults.properties
Setting default log level to "WARN".
To adjust logging level use sc.setLogLevel(newLevel). For SparkR, use setLogLevel(newLevel).
17/05/14 13:21:25 WARN NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
17/05/14 13:21:34 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/c:/Spark/bin/../jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/jars/datanucleus-rdbms-3.2.9.jar."
17/05/14 13:21:34 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/c:/Spark/bin/../jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/jars/datanucleus-core-3.2.10.jar."
17/05/14 13:21:34 WARN General: Plugin (Bundle) "org.datanucleus.api.jdo" is already registered. Ensure you dont have multiple JAR versions of the same plugin in the classpath. The URL "file:/c:/Spark/bin/../jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar" is already registered, and you are trying to register an identical plugin located at URL "file:/C:/Spark/jars/datanucleus-api-jdo-3.2.6.jar."
17/05/14 13:21:48 WARN ObjectStore: Failed to get database global_temp, returning NoSuchObjectException
Spark context Web UI available at http://192.168.1.9:4040
Spark context available as 'sc' (master = local[*], app id = local-1494764489031).
Spark session available as 'spark'.
Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /___/ .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 2.1.1
      /_/

Using Scala version 2.11.8 (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.8.0_131)
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.
```

Comment: Hi Samson. Thank you for your feedback. I am very new to coding and Spark. I would like to solve the above issue, because as I understand, Spark won't work on my computer.

Comment: For the record, `Unable to load native-hadoop library` will be an issue if you have to connect to a Hadoop cluster with Kerberos authentication. Since you don't seem to work for an Investment Bank, you shouldn't have to bother :-)

Answer (score 1):

There's no issue in your output. These `WARN` messages can simply be ignored.

In other words, it *looks* like you've installed Spark 2.1.1 on Windows 10 properly.

To make sure you installed it properly (so I could remove *looks* from above sentence) is to do the following:

```
spark.range(1).show
```

That by default will trigger loading Hive classes that may or may not end up with exceptions on Windows due to Hadoop's requirements (and hence the need for `winutils.exe` to work them around).